# What is the volume inside $S$, which is the surface given by the level set $\{ (x,y,z): x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 =1 \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, volume

The solution given uses a linear algebraic argument that doesn't seem very instructive -- and may not even be correct, I think.

We notice from the equation, that the surface is a quadratic form, level set = 1.

$\bullet$ The solution rewrites it as $x^TAx$,

$\bullet$ Finds a symmetric matrix $A$ that gives the resulting quadratic form,

$\bullet$ Computes the eigenvalues of $A$,

And then (here's where the explanation doesn't really follow, I think)

$\bullet$ A change of variables is made so that the surface becomes an ellipsoid,

$\bullet$ Finally using the volume of an ellipsoid formula, the final answer is given.

Is there another / better way of finding the volume of $S$?

Thanks,

Comment: You may use three dimensional integral.

Comment: Hi @MehdiJafarniaJahromi, can you be a little more specific?  With which coordinates -- spherical, I'm guessing -- and with what integrand ... the integrand "1"?  The xy-term is causing some trouble, so far.  And with what limits of integration, since it's not obvious at all that it is an ellipsoid.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MehdiJafarniaJahromi - so, I switched over to spherical coordinates and am getting a very nasty lower and upper limit of integration for the innermost integral, and the limits of integration of this innermost integral involves all three integration variables, r, theta, and phi, namely because of the xy-term, I think. Do you have any further suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First look at the elliptical cross-section in xy-plane:

$\{ (x,y): x^2 + xy + y^2 = 1 \}$

It is clear that this is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so write

$x^2 + xy + y^2 = a(x+y)^2 + b(x-y)^2$ so by equating coefficients $a=\frac{3}{4}, b=\frac{1}{4}$

Therefore $\boxed{\dfrac{3}{4}(x+y)^2 + \dfrac{1}{4}(x-y)^2 = 1}$

Changing to new coordinate system: $X = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(x+y\Big), Y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(x-y\Big)$ (where the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ terms ensure that the new axes are of unit length), and writing in standard form:

$\dfrac{X^2}{({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}})^2} + \dfrac{Y^2}{({\sqrt{2}})^2} = 1$,  or for the full level set $\boxed{\dfrac{X^2}{({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}})^2} + \dfrac{Y^2}{({\sqrt{2}})^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{1^2} = 1}$

Hence, the level set is an ellipsoid with semi-axes of lengths $R_X = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ , $R_Y = \sqrt{2}$ and $R_Z = 1$.

So the volume is $\dfrac{4}{3}\pi \cdot R_X \cdot R_Y \cdot R_Z = \dfrac{8 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$